# Add a control to a parent form, in design time, through a custom component

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, components

I have create a **custom component** which changes some **properties** of it's **parent form** when **placed** in **design time**. But I also want this **component**, in **design time** again, to **add** some **controls** to it's **parent form**.

I tried something like this code example below, but with no luck. The added control placed on the form, but I can't select it, just stands there!!! Any idea what exactly am I doing wrong?

```
Public Class MyCustomComponent
     Private _MyControl As New MyUserControl

     '...Rest of my code

     Private Sub OnPlace()
           '...Rest of my code
          _ParentForm.Controls.Add(_MyControl)
     End Sub

     Private Sub OnDispose()
           '...Rest of my code
          _MyControl.Dispose()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the additional controls be part of the UserControl if it is required?  Its a rather bad design for controls to be aware of each other/interect etc

Comment: I have create two user controls. The first one takes the place of form's title bar. With an icon on the left, custom form title, custom control box, etc. The other one, is placed at the bottom of the form, as bottom bar, with a form resize handler and some other options. The form, in which user controls will be placed, should be borderless etc. So I though it would be better to make a custom component too, which will changes some parent form's properties and also place those two user controls at once, so to avoid one by one placement and the manual form's properties adjustment.

Comment: You do not show how you are creating these controls, but I suspect that they are not being created via the Winform designer host.  The Winform designer has specific rules and methods for adding controls to the design surface.  You need to obtain a reference to the [IDesignerHost Interface sevice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.idesignerhost(v=vs.110).aspx) and then use its [CreateComponent method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bes9k699(v=vs.110).aspx).  You will still need to set the create control's parent and other properties/